# exporting from freemind

Tags: mindmapping, freemind

In order to embed a map created in freemind  as it looks in the tool, into my web based application I would need to export it as javascript. is that right?
Also where would I get some help/tips to like attach js events to 'onclick' of the nodes?
I need to perform actions like

1. move the diagram to the side and display a Div like box container below the node as the title with all required content inside it?
2. when I click on the node again the box should hide again and the map should be centered again.

are there any examples of free-mind maps like these?

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is probably exporting it as XML, then using an XSLT to put it inside HTML. This might be pretty involved.

Comment: ok.. Thanks... It would be great if you have a working sample... I also tried the exporting as Java Applet option from the tool and its generating an Html which is the same clickable diagram in the tool..